# Bacteria without plasmid

Tags: microbiology

I am currently working on antibiotic resistance and I would be very interested to know which bacteria has no plasmid, in a similar way than *M. tuberculosis*.
This would help me a lot for my work and I did not succeed to get that much information online.

Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at *Bacillus subtilis*. Most of the lab strains don't contain plasmids, though they have been found in some environmental isolates.

https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/21/4/337/490925

All this depends on exactly what you're looking for: a species with no known plasmids in any isolates, or some commonly used lab strains with no plasmids?

*M. tb* is a pretty unique case. Most of the other species in the *Mycobacterium* genus do contain plasmids.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, this will be very usefull !
I am looking for bacteria which, as MTB does not share (or sharing few) plasmids so the antibiotic resistance cannot be detected by mapping their genomes with common antibiotic resistance genes. Some just as MTB, which have developped SNP which induce resistance.

Comment: Another way to approach this is to do it by genes rather than organism. For instance, gyrase and topoisomerase proteins are targeted by some antibiotics. Because these are produced by essential genes, resistance has to arise from point mutations (more or less). So you could look at these genes across a wide range of organisms. Just depends on what your objective is.